# "Je doute qu'aucun d'eux (ne)"

Tags: négation, double-négation

According to electronic translation, the sentence

> Je doute qu'aucun d'eux ne comprenne ton discours.

means

> I doubt any of them understand what you're saying.

This translation may not be perfect, but is its *general* sense correct?  (I.e. the speaker believes that none of the listeners understands.)

Assuming the answer to the last question is close enough to "yes", how would one say this in French?:

> I doubt any of them **does not** understand what you're saying.

Answer (score 1):

- This translation may not be perfect, but is its general sense correct? (I.e. the speaker believes that none of the listeners understands.)

*Je doute* is a little bit ambiguous.
If you say "Je doute qu'aucun d'eux ne comprenne ton discours" it may be understood as the speaker **does not** believe in the fact that none of the listeners understands, i.e. he believes that at least someone understood. *Je doute* is like *Je ne pense pas*. To avoid ambiguity, you can say

> Je pense qu'aucun d'entre eux ne comprend ton discours.

- how would one say this in French?: I doubt any of them does not understand what you're saying.

Linked with the previous sentence, you could translate it this way:

> Je ne pense pas qu'aucun d'entre eux ne comprend ton discours.

Or, to avoid double negation:

> Je pense qu'ils comprennent tous ton discours.